# PL/SQL pre defined Statement in cursor definition

Tags: sql, loops, plsql

We have a `select` statement which differs depending on switches. Then we loop over the result.

Currently the code looks like:

```
if switch_a then
    for rec in 
    (
        select * 
                order by decode(x, y,1,0),
                decode(x,a,2,0),
                decode(x,z,3,0), pos
    )
    loop ...
end loop;
else 
for rec in 
        (
            select * 
                    order by decode(x, y,1,0),
                    decode(x,z,3,0), pos
        )
        loop ...
end loop;
end if;
```

Now I would like to transform that code to be only one loop. So I go with:

```
if (switch_a) then
    Statement call := select*...
else
    Statement call := select*...
end if;

for rec in call
loop

end loop;
```

The issue is, that I don´t know if this works in a for rec in and I don´t know how to define an executable SQL statement. Is this possible and if so, can you give an example?

Comment: seems to be part of the sollution. However i would have to define the cursors outside of the function, which would not allow to fill the same cursor with two different Statements depending on the result i get from my If clause.
This would cause me to still have to use two different loops and i would not gain cleaner code. 
Am i missing something?

Comment: Is it just the order by that's different in your query? You didn't include the from and where clauses in your example, so it's difficult to tell. An alternative to I3rutt's answer would be to pull all the logic inside both loops into a separate procedure (with the necessary parameters), and then you just need to call the procedure from inside both loops.

Comment: The statement does only differ on the "order by" part.
if the switch is true, there is an additional order by condition,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as it's just the order by that's different, I'd use a non-Boolean (SQL doesn't know about Booleans in Oracle) flag to decide whether to include the column or not in the order by, e.g.:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 col1, 100 col2, 200 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 col1, 90 col2, 210 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 col1, 80 col2, 220 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 col1, 70 col2, 230 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 5 col1, 60 col2, 240 col3 FROM dual)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   sample_data
ORDER BY CASE WHEN :p_switch_a_flag = 'y' THEN col2 END,
         col3;
```

Running that with `:p_switch_a_flag = 'n'`:

```
      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        200
         2         90        210
         3         80        220
         4         70        230
         5         60        240
```

Running that with `:p_switch_a_flag = 'y'`:

```
      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         5         60        240
         4         70        230
         3         80        220
         2         90        210
         1        100        200
```

That way, you only have one cursor, regardless of how the flag is set, and your code would look something like:

```
-- if you can't change the switch_a Boolean to a varchar2 flag, then
-- manually set the switch_a flag, otherwise you'd simply pass in
-- the flag as a varchar2, rather than a Boolean.
if switch_a then 
  switch_a_flag := 'y';
end if;

for rec in (select * 
            from    ....
            order by decode(x, y,1,0),
                     case when switch_a_flag = 'y' then decode(x,a,2,0) end,
                     decode(x,z,3,0),
                     pos)
loop
  ...
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like that:

```
declare 
  Statement_call varchar2(4000); 
  rec sys_refcursor;  
  l_row number;
begin
    if (switch_a) then
      Statement_call := 'select 1 as q from dual';
    else
      Statement_call := 'select 2 as q from dual';
    end if;

    OPEN rec FOR Statement_call;
    loop
      FETCH rec INTO l_row;
      EXIT WHEN rec%NOTFOUND;

      dbms_output.put_line(l_row);
    end loop;   
    CLOSE rec;

end;
```